# How to use PrimeFaces Captcha?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, captcha, recaptcha

I went through the [user guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html) and the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/captcha.jsf) but couldn't find a way to get the Captcha evaluation result in the backing bean. I can see the result on the top message bar on the UI but how to get the result in the backing bean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that it has any result for your beans. If you type valid text in the captcha box the *process validation phase* does not throw error and your input will be handled as valid. Otherwise the captcha component signal the error and you will see the error message with the `h:message` or the `h:messages` tag. (Maybe you should attach some code.)

> "If an entered value is invalid, an error message is added to
>   FacesContext, and the component is marked invalid. If a component is
>   marked invalid, JSF advances to the render response phase, which will
>   display the current view with the validation error messages. If there
>   are no validation errors, JSF advances to the update model values
>   phase."

(From http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/)

Comment: Thanks! you are right. turns out I just need to put the captcha in the page and let JSF take care of it.