# Can I use the PrimeFaces captcha from their showcase as it is?

Tags: java, primefaces, recaptcha, captcha

I ve tried the latest PrimeFaces Captcha on their showcase:

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/captcha.xhtml

and read an existing question on stackexchange:

[How to use PrimeFaces Captcha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546542/how-to-use-primefaces-captcha)

I am still not sure how (and whether) the captcha on the primcefaces page does work. Whenever I click with my mouse somewhoere on it, it alsways says : "Correct" . So even I always click on one and the same place, it says "Correct". Is that all simple ?!!! Can I use the showcase in my code as it is?

Thank you

Comment: Hello, try it in a New private window. May be you have the captcha cached in your browser. And also you have to put your <param-name>primefaces.PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name> and <param-name>primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name> in web.xml as a context-param

Comment: @manelseo, thank you. This part is already working. Now I have another problem, but I will post it in a separate question

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Captcha starts to work after several cliks on it - I made maybe seven or ten clicks which  were all accepted, but afterwards the capctha started to behave as a "real" captcha showing me pictures and asking me questions about the pictures.

Important: before using the primeFaces captcha on their showcase, one must update the web.xml file with two important parameters as shown here:

[Primefaces 5: captcha does not work for 'javax.servlet.ServletException: Expression cannot be null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924006/primefaces-5-captcha-does-not-work-for-javax-servlet-servletexception-express)